# Add "Take No Action" to Windows 7 AutoPlay dialog

Tags: windows

Is there any way to add "Take No Action" to the AutoPlay dialog boxes that pop up when inserting media/devices? I'd like to have the options of setting it as the default for any future media/device without having to go into the control panel every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make **Take no action** the default option, it's like turning off AutoPlay.

To turn AutoPlay feature off,

1. Click Start button on the Taskbar.
2. Type `autoplay` in the search box.
3. Click **AutoPlay** in Control Panel group.
4. Clear **Use AutoPlay for all media and devices** checkbox.

Alternatively you can select **Take no action** from the list of actions for some of media types and/or devices.

Comment: Ah, but I still want the autoplay dialog to come up. I just want the addition of **Take no action** to be an option alongside of the others. That way I can set take no action as the default for some devices and leave the window to pop up each time for others.

Comment: I think Microsoft removed **Take no action** from the AutoPlay dialog for clarity: this action is the same as closing the dialog — so one action less in the list of possible actions. You can go to AutoPlay Control Panel and select **Take no action** as the default for those media types and devices you don't want to see the AutoPlay dialog.

Comment: It's not the same, as there's no option to make closing/no action the default for a given device without having to go through an unnecessary extra step of going to the Control Panel.

Comment: If you cancel out of the popup... it pops up again next time - because there is still no default. "Take no action" removes the popup from future events - because TNA is now the default. I've been asking myself the same question - why isn't TNA an option on the popup screen. I want it to popup and include TNA as well.